# Rest API single item - json format problem

Tags: php, json, rest

My API return single item as object:

```
"data":{"id":1,"name":"Test"}
```

but i need this item in array, like this:

```
"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Test"}]
```

data.json:

```
[
  {"id": 1, "name":"Test"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "Test2"}
]
```

api.php:

```
function getData2($id) {
 $jsonString = '';
 $jsonData = file_get_contents($jsonString);
 $data2 = json_decode($jsonData, true);
 return $data2[$id - 1];
}
if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
 $a = getData2($_GET['id']);
}
response($a);
function response($data) {
 header("HTTP/1.1 ".$status);
 $response['data'] = $data;
 $jsonResponse = json_encode($response);
 echo $jsonResponse;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put data in an array like this:

```
function response($data) {
header("HTTP/1.1 ".'200');

$response['data'] = [$data];

$jsonResponse = json_encode($response);
echo $jsonResponse;
}
```

notice $data in this line `$response['data'] = [$data];`